# Protractor randomly doesn't synchronize to an Angular page

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-strap

I am using Protractor 4.0.14 to test an Angular application.

Lately, I have been getting random errors and I don't understand why. It's like Protractor is loosing the synchronization.

I try to prevent that by disabling the synchronization myself and wait for elements to be present.
But in the end, protractor doesn't wait for the page to be loaded to execute the test so I get different errors like :

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

or this :

```
document unloaded while waiting for result
```

For instance, on 10 executions I may get one error on the line :

```
return $('#information-email').getAttribute('value') != '';
```

I try to wait that the element is fully loaded with the content inside before doing anything.
The normal waitForAngular that is executed by protractor doesn't wait for the field to be populated so I disabled the synchronization even if it is actually an angular page. But it fails to wait for the element.

```
it('Should change user email', function() {
    $('#information-email').clear().sendKeys(browser.params.login.userExtra);
    $('#my-information button[type="submit"]').click();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.wait(function () {
        return $('div.toast.toast-success').isPresent();
    });
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    expect($('div.toast.toast-success').isPresent()).toBe(true);
    $$('button.toast-close-button').each(function (item) {
        item.click();
    });
});

it('Should check that the user is saved', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.wait(function () {
        return $('#information-email').getAttribute('value') != '';
    });
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    expect($('#information-email').getAttribute('value')).toEqual(browser.params.login.userExtra);
});
```

Also, when I load a page with browser.get, sometimes the page is not fully loaded and tests are executed before angular is loaded when ignoreSynchronization is false.

So I'm a bit lost because I didn't have these problems few weeks ago. Could it be a parameter in the conf.js that I miss or is it an angular timeout breaking the synchronization? Any Idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do so, you should avoid the aSynch - Synch problems using beforeEach and afterEach for the purpose:

```
beforeEach(function(){
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});

afterEach(function(){
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

Also using .waitForAngular() instead ignoreSynch should avoid some synch issues too.

Comment: The waitForAngular brought me many issues with "document unloaded while waiting for result". And by default, the waitForAngular is supposed to be called automatically from what I understood, when the page is loading after the promises are resolved.

I will try to use the beforeEach.afterEach in a new describe to see if it changes anything. But when I tried it, it didn't help with the "unloaded document" error.

Comment: You should try using the waitForAngular after you request the page and before start your testing, let me know if it helps. About the "unloaded document" it seems like the problem is happening when the function is interrupted by some redirection/action. Your problem appeared when Chrome applied on of his updates, did you try to specify the version instead using latest?